# Javascript : Uncaught ReferenceError: calculator_test is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

what am I missing I've got error message :  Uncaught ReferenceError: calculator_test is not defined

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button</p>
<button onclick="calculator_test()">test</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/calculator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

calculator.js:

```
calculator_test  = function(){
    alert("factorial function is broken");

}
```

Comment: Error is what error says. Check 1) that the script resource was fetched correctly (ie. HTTP 200 OK) and; 2) there are no console error messages while loading said script.

Comment: GET http://localhost:63342/calculator.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: calculator_test is not defined
  onclick index.html:5

Comment: So that's the problem: "404 [calculator.js] Not Found". The `src` used to the script element is incorrect.

Comment: internal linkage works properly and the file is in the project repository

Comment: Don't doubt the messages. If it "worked properly" there would not be a 404 server response.

Comment: true, the file is showed by the browser there but there is no code in it

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem:

My problem was that my IDE was auto-completing src="/ with src="/calculator.js" and was finding the file path.

But the right path was src="calculator.js" without the slash

thanks